# python string-to-date function. I need to add the correct year to result based on today's date and the month in the string

Tags: python, datetime, scrapy

Using scrapy and python I am collecting tour dates from webpages.

The year is not present in the field e.g. '11th November' or '21st January' which is fine because I can add a year doing the string-to-date conversion using the following code:

```
def sortdate(self, mydate):  
    newdate = datetime.strptime(
        re.sub(r"\b([0123]?[0-9])(st|th|nd|rd)\b", r"\1", mydate) + " " + str(datetime.now().year),
        "%d %B %Y")
    return newdate
```

This turns '11th November' into 'datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 11, 0, 0)'
which is perfect.

My issue now is that it adds 2019 to everything, even next year's dates. So I need to assess today's date (today is 13th November 2019) and then when it does the conversation it will add the correct year. e.g. '11th January' will get 2020 but '12th November' would now get 2020 as well (since today's date has passed the threshold).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for help modifying the date output depending on whether the input day has has already occurred on this year's calendar. In order to do that, I put most of your logic (good job on that, btw) into a function that we can use twice.

We'll run it once with the current year, and compare the output to `datetime.now()`, and if the date is less than `now()` then it's in the past. In that case, we'll run the same logic again, but with this year +1.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

def set_date(date, year):
    regex_date = re.sub( r"\b([0123]?[0-9])(st|th|nd|rd)\b", r"\1", date)
    new_date = datetime.strptime(f"{regex_date} {year}", "%d %B %Y")
    return new_date

def sort_date(date):
    now = datetime.now()
    new_date = set_date(date, now.year)
    if new_date < now:
        new_date = set_date(date, now.year + 1)
    return new_date

this_year = sort_date("20 November")
next_year = sort_date("1 November")

print(this_year)
print(next_year)
```

Outputs:

```
2019-11-20 00:00:00
2020-11-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: I am trying to grasp how this is working, can you explain what this bit of code does:  datetime.strptime(f"{regex_date} {year}", "%d %B %Y")

Comment: This is python 3's optimized tool for string concatenation. It's functionally the same as writing `regex_date + " " + year`. You can stick strings together any way you like, so don't feel like you need to use this. However, if you want to read up on it, [here's a primer on fstrings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).